# Diophantine equation: $18x^2 + 36y^2 =x^2 y^2$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

Does anyone know an algorithm for solving this kind of diophantine equation? Are there any solutions?

Comment: WolframAlpha can tell you *if* there are any [solutions in the first place](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+18x%5E2%2B36y%5E2%3Dx%5E2y%5E2)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hint: rewrite the equation as
$$x^2y^2-18x^2-36y^2 + 18\cdot 36 = 18\cdot 36$$
or
$$(x^2-36)(y^2-18) = 648.$$

Comment: I am somewhat new to discrete mathematics, could you explain the procedure after this?

Comment: on the left-hand side, you have product of two (possibly negative) integers. You can try to decompose the right-hand side into such a product and match the pair. It is possible since $648$ has a small number of divisors.

Comment: @tørketrommeldamp Just a note: this problem falls in the domain of number theory, not discrete mathematics.